# Solution to REST API caching for Python Flask app served through wsgi/nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, caching

I'm trying to cache the response to API http requests in Python/Flask using WSGI/nginx. I used to use the Flask `simplecache` library for running small standalone Flask apps. Those apps are now behind an WSGI/nginx layer, which makes them much more scalable but I am wondering if there is a way to cache the API response at this level? I was hoping nginx would handle that, but I'm stumped when I Google it.

E.g. cache the results of `http://results.com?page=5` for 3 hrs.

The lack of questions and answers on this top makes me think I am somehow asking the wrong question.